# How to conditionally change the type in typescript in angular?

Tags: typescript, types

I am making an angular component dependent on the API Response.
I am getting these from an API Response.

1. When there's no error

   Data : {
   Status: string;
   Data: number;
   }
2. When there's an Error I am getting this.

   Data : {
   Status: string;
   Error: string;
   Message: string;
   }

As we can see Status is common I tried implementing this.

```
interface ApiModel {
  Status: string;
}

interface DataModel extends ApiModel {
  Data: number;
}
interface ErrorModel extends ApiModel {
  ErrorCode: string;
  Message: string;
}
```

I am trying to use the typescript to give it my variable an option where it can be either one and then pass that type in it's response too.

I don't want to use optional type here hence I am facing these issues.

What I am expecting is,

```
if (typeof Response === DataModel){
Response: DataModel;
// Other code
}
else {
Response:ErrorModel;
// Other code
}
```

The API call here

```
getReminder(reminderId: number) {
    const API_URL = `${this.BASE_URL}users/${this.userId}/reminders/${reminderId}`;
    return this.httpClient.get<ErrorModel | DataModel>(API_URL, this.options).pipe(
      map((data: ErrorModel | DataModel) => {
        return data;
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you please send the exact function that is calling api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through all the above answers I came to the conclusion that conditionally altering the interface is possible in TS but not possible in angular components.
Hence,

```
interface ApiModel {
Status: string;
Data?: string;
ErrorCode?: string;
Message?: string;
}
```

Although this might seem like a cheaper or a much simpler version, I was targeting this.

Alternatively, Using Class also works. There I can define conditional type as in a class there's logic that can be used but if we are to use interface then the above solution is much simpler and easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

To my eyes your model looks like [Discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions)

If you model it correctly, the compiler will be able to do the narrowing without extra code.
Note that:

- there is no need to downcast after the type predicate check
- discriminator checks one of two union members - if it is not DataModel, the compiler can deduce that it is an ErrorModel

```ts
interface DataModel {
  Status: 'success';
  Data: number;
}

interface ErrorModel {
  Status: 'error'
  ErrorCode: string;
  Message: string;
}

type ApiModel = DataModel | ErrorModel;

function foo(responseData: ApiModel): void {
  if (responseData.Status === 'success') {
    console.log(responseData.Data);
  } else {
    console.log(responseData.ErrorCode);
  }
}

foo({Status: 'success', Data: 10});
```

If you cannot model your data as a discriminated union, you still model the response as a union, but you will have to resort to a [Type predicate] to verify which member of the union you are dealing with

```ts
interface ApiModelBase {
  Status: string;
}

interface DataModel extends ApiModelBase {
  Data: number;
}
interface ErrorModel extends ApiModelBase {
  ErrorCode: string;
  Message: string;
}

type ApiModel = DataModel | ErrorModel;


function isDataModel(response: ApiModel): response is DataModel {
  return (response as DataModel).Data !== undefined;
}

function foo(responseData: ApiModel): void {
  if (isDataModel(responseData)) {
    console.log(responseData.Data);
  } else {
    console.log(responseData.ErrorCode);
  }
}

foo({Status: 's1', Data: 10});
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=36&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHAsgewCYQA2yA3gFDLIDKmYArgM4BcyA5A3Qkgw6wNwU0GOCxB0AtgCNoAgL5lQkWIhQBRKFBxRcBYuUo0MjFq2iaorQevMBhfBBYMwUUAHMBlLBB5xXD5E4uIO5k8mRgAJ4ADigAglHAOkTIALxCmEnEAD7I1lqZAmQwdCAIYMA4IMgwODgAFFDeUZUMEOiYLPGJ9oQAlCwAbjjAeKSCwDDIDU0tbcIAdIb0DKkpaeyc3Ly9Y5SUCC04hBDzhDiu0wzNIK3tcPN3vR7IsshErbt7BzdHJ2cXjSuszu8zyUDsBCegnkYRq9RIS2MbA4XG8vAANOkRMgAIwABlkTyAA)

Comment: The code works in TS I am trying to implement the same in angular.

Comment: You tagged your question with typescript tag - I assume you are using TS in your angular project. What prevents you from using this snippet in your project? What errors do you receive?

Comment: Using your function is still giving me an error in angular. I am quite new at angular and js/ts and this came up as a task. While I tried implementing it theoretically should work but I am getting this error 

Property 'Data' does not exist on type 'ApiModel'.
  Property 'Data' does not exist on type 'DeleteErrorModel'.

In angular, it won't let you compile unless all the problems are resolved in ts.

Comment: There is no `DeleteErrorModel` in your question - perhaps your problem is more complex than shown in the question.

Comment: That appeared by mistakes sorry for that, the delete error model is error model, for privacy purposes I cannot share everything hence that occurred.

Comment: This works! But as I am using API responses, the one that @IAM5K gave is more useful in my case.
Thanks again!

Comment: Good that you got this working - I think that my solution has the benefit over selected one - no downcast is necessary after properly done narrowing - thus I'll keep mine here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this pattern to test what type you are receiving with some inline type conversion:

```js
function isDataModel(response: ApiModel): response is DataModel {
  return (response as DataModel).Data !== undefined;
}

// when `responseData` is the actual response received from the API
const responseData: ApiModel = ...;

if (isDataModel(responseData)) {
  // The response is of type DataModel
  const dataResponse: DataModel = responseData;
  // Other code for DataModel
} else {
  // The response is of type ErrorModel
  const errorResponse: ErrorModel = responseData;
  // Other code for ErrorModel
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Union type in TypeScript to achieve what you want?

```
type YourResponse = DataModel | ErrorModel;
```

This could be the example usage:

```
const response: YourResponse = {
  Status: "Success",
  Data: 100,
};

if (response instanceof DataModel) {
  It is a DataModel.
} else if (response instanceof ErrorModel) {
  It is an ErrorModel.
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the DataModel is a type and is being used as a value instead.

Comment: `instanceof` check is not appropriate - DataModel is not in the prototype chain as it is an interface. See [instanceof narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#instanceof-narrowing)

Comment: roger that @Lesiak, the answer you have posted seems helpful which use `isDataModel` function to validate instead of `instanceof`

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

isDataModel(response: ApiModel): response is DataModel {
  return response.Status === 'success';
}

getReminder(reminderId: number): Observable<DataModel | ErrorModel> {
  const API_URL = `${this.BASE_URL}users/${this.userId}/reminders/${reminderId}`;
  return this.httpClient.get<ApiModel>(API_URL, this.options).pipe(
    map((response: ApiModel) => {
      if (isDataModel(response)) {
        const responseData: DataModel = response as DataModel;
        return responseData;
      } else {
        // ErrorModel handling
        const errorResponse: ErrorModel = response as ErrorModel;
        throw errorResponse;
      }
    })
  );
}
```

Interfaces can be as earlier

```js
interface ApiModel {
  Status: string;
}

interface DataModel extends ApiModel {
  Data: number;
}

interface ErrorModel extends ApiModel {
  ErrorCode: string;
  Message: string;
}
```